# GWT - image upload and preview

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I've just watched the lib examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted)... The thing is I am looking for a standard solution for GWT image upload as

- A) Upload image to client app
- B) Preview image in client app
- C) Get image in base64 (from upload object) on client app

Is there such lib for GWT 2.3+ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/). With Gwtupload you can upload an image,preview this image and  see the progress bar with real information about the process (file size, bytes transferred, etc).

You can also choose from simple and multiple file upload.